# Tradingview alert placeholder UPPERCASE

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I would like to user tradingview alert placeholder to insert my comments in order to entry the order.

I have no right to edit the source code.
Therefore only can use placeholder to do something

Any solution to make {{strategy.market_position}} output become upper case (LONG, SHORT, FLAT) instead of (long, short ,flat)

Comment: Please check this https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021-how-to-use-a-variable-value-in-alert/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the case of the placeholders. They are automatically generated and you cannot call any functions etc. in the alert message.